# How to get a range of string in Android?

Tags: android, range

Currently i am working in simple android app, I have tried to range of string in iphone, its works, but i didn't know this in Android app?
In iphone:

```
result = "mobile - check balance | rate: 0.036"

if ( [result rangeOfString:@"rate:"].location != NSNotFound) 
{

}
```

How to convert this in Android, please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something like 
    result = "mobile- check balance | rate: 0.036"

```
if( result.indexOf("rate")!=-1)
{}
```

I've been using objective-c recently too, and I pulled this from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: i have one doubt, can u help me?

Comment: In iphone - 
if ([result hasPrefix:@"rate:"]){   }, how to conver this in android?

Comment: id(result.startsWith("rate:"))

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    String strVowels = "mobile - check balance | rate: 0.036";
    if (strVowels.contains("rate:") == true) {
        // String contains IOU sub-string!
        Log.i("mylog", "this word is in string.");
    } else {
        Log.i("mylog", "this word is not in string.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you mean [String.contains()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `rangeOfString` usage is roughly equivalent to [`String#indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String result = "mobile - check balance | rate: 0.036";

if (result.indexOf("rate:") != -1) 
{

}
```

but you can write this more clearly in Java with [`String#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
if (result.contains("rate:")) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `String.indexOf` and then combine the value returned with the length of the String you're looking for.

The `indexOf` function returns the index of the first letter of the string you passed in so that can be treated as your "zero" position.

Alternatively, as Matt Ball points out, the way you're using it, the `String.contains` method would be just as effective, if not slightly cleaner.

Comment: result =@"Error: access denied"  In iphone - if ([result hasPrefix:@"Error:"]){ }, how to conver this in android? please help me

Comment: `result = "Error: access denied"; if(result.startsWith("Error:")){}`